# TLS handshake fail. HTTPS request to HAproxy to http and then encrypt it again to forward request to ssl server

Tags: linux, ssl, haproxy

Need help!!! . I have an https request and need to intercept it, read values and forward the same `ssl` request to the destination. I have all the required `crt`, `key`, `CA` with me. I am aware that Haproxy ACL does not work with L4 layer but I'm trying to find a workaround to decrypt the message, read the message, encrypt it again and forward. The reason for reading message is to using ACL i need to read the path difference in carious request and route the request to different servers accordingly.  I am trying to intercept the client request to server, the request by default is SSL and server is expecting an SSL request

ssl crt: created a new user with new crt-key pair and used Certificate Signing Requests of server to authenticate it against CA in server

The scenario is that I have an incoming SSL request which I'm capturing into frontend of haproxy with the server certificate, while forwarding that request to a test webserver I am able to see that it has changed from HTTPS to HTTP. Now when I try re-encrypt it, the original destination is not able to accept the request since it is not SSL, I have tried to add the certs in the backend but not useful. Please check my current Haproxy config and please help if possible. I am not an expert in  Network communication/ Encryption/ HaProxy.

```
frontend test
    bind IP:6443 ssl crt <location>
    option httplog
    mode http
    default_backend testback
backend testback
    mode http
    balance roundrobin
    option http-check
    server <host> IP:6443 check fall 3 rise 2 ssl verify required ca-file <loc> crt <loc>
```

> To verify my certicates are valid and connecting:
> openssl s_client -connect :6443 -cert myuser.crt -key myuser.key -CAfile ca.crt
> Output:
>
> ```
> SSL handshake has read 1619 bytes and written 2239 bytes
> Verification: OK
> ```

So no problem with Certicates i presume, problem while using Ha proxy for connection

> Error:
> Unable to connect to the server: x509: certificate specifies an incompatible key usage
>
> Ha proxy error:
> 2021-08-12T14:45:36.930478+02:00 parasilo-27 haproxy[21562]: :34672 [12/Aug/2021:14:45:36.927] server/1: SSL handshake failure
> 2021-08-12T14:45:37+02:00 localhost haproxy[21562]: :34674 [12/Aug/2021:14:45:37.438] server/1: SSL handshake failure

Comment: Few things: 1. haproxy ACL can work with L7 if that layer is HTTP and configured to `mode http`, which you do. 2. config looks ok for this purpose. 3. add some logs from haproxy, some requests you make and errors you get, so the actual problem is easier to figure out

Comment: hi @tbielaszewski, thank you for the reply. I made that statement wrong, I meant ACL does not work for L4 (TCP), I have edited that part now. After testing out for a while I saw it in some documentation. 3) The connection is going forward to the actual back end server. But server is not able to recognize this request. But in normal port forwarding with Haproxy it works perfect. Its working is in Kubernetes, I am trying to implement an interceptor between Kubectl CLI and Kubeapi server

Comment: hey again @tbielaszewski, I have logged the errors and reedited the entire question. please look through.

Comment: `certificate specifies an incompatible key usage` means problem is with SSL certificates. check `openssl x509 -in /path/to/cert.pem -noout -ext extendedKeyUsage` if shows something like `X509v3 Extended Key Usage: TLS Web Server Authentication, TLS Web Client Authentication` or whatever else your client may need - that's sometimes arbitrary and requires study of software's documentation or guessing. i don't know kubernetes, so i can't help with its needs. you may also try comparing working and not working certificates in regards to key usage.

Comment: Hey @tbielaszewski, Thank you, i guess this surely gave me a lead to work on.. I did get " X509v3 Extended Key Usage: TLS Web Client Authentication". Is there anyway we can make this suitable to proceed the request? I have searched documentations, git, stackoverflow, all other things but till now not able to find any suitable answers.

Comment: Which cert does have `X509v3 Extended Key Usage: TLS Web Client Authentication`? Cert on haproxy frontend will most likely need `TLS Web Server Authentication` as well.

Comment: Hey @tbielaszewski, Thank you so much!! it worked finally!!!!!!  So I used a 509v3 Extended Key Usage: TLS Web Server Authentication in the frontend and 509v3 Extended Key Usage: TLS Web Client Authentication in the backend and Voila!!!

Comment: @tbielaszewski would you mind posting your comment/s as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To sum up what was analyzed in the comments, as asked. Perhaps it will be useful to somebody someday.
Haproxy's config turned out to be correct, but generated certificates had wrong `extended key usage` (X509v3 extension).
Command to list `extended key usage`:

```
openssl x509 -in /path/to/cert.pem -noout -ext extendedKeyUsage
```

Often, when bought on internet, it shows `X509v3 Extended Key Usage: TLS Web Server Authentication, TLS Web Client Authentication`. Original Poster used self-signed, self-generated certificates and his certificate used on haproxy's frontend had only `TLS Web Client Authentication`, where frontend requires `TLS Web Server Authentication` if this extensions is used at all.
That resulted in the error message:

```
Error: kubectl get po: Unable to connect to the server: x509: certificate specifies an incompatible key usage
```

As a consequence haproxy logged `SSL handshake failure` without any more details, as is its habit.

After adding `TLS Web Server Authentication` to certificate in haproxy's frontend section and `TLS Web Client Authentication` to certificate in haproxy's backend section Original Poster reported success.